# Data don't passed to the database

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an asp.net core project, the controller have two actions with the name "create" first one called the creation page (get method), second one for the creation action (post method).
The first action get the page successfully, but the second one doesn't pass the data to the data base noting that when I'm running the project with debug mode, the object which hold data for the model is contain the data.

First photo one shows that it's has the data, but it's not adding data to the data base.
Second photo shows the page which read from the table, and it's empty.
Model:

```
namespace CTS_System6.Models
{
    public class TranslatorsLanguages
    { 
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TranslatorId { get; set; }
        public int FromLanguage { get; set; }
        public int ToLanguage { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("TranslatorId")]
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("FromLanguage, ToLanguage")]
        public Languages Languages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
        // GET: TranslatorLanguagesController/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var translatorid = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

            ViewBag.TID = translatorid;
            return View();
        }

        // POST: TranslatorLanguagesController/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(TranslatorsLanguages language)
        {
            try
            {
                translatorRepository.Add(language);

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, e.Message);
                return View();
            }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

TranslatorLanguagesRepository:

```
    public class TranslatorsLanguagesRepository : ITranslatorRepository<TranslatorsLanguages>
    {


        TranslatorAppDbContext db;


        public TranslatorsLanguagesRepository(TranslatorAppDbContext _db)
        {
            db = _db;
        }

        public void Add(TranslatorsLanguages entity)
        {
            db.TranslatorsLanguages.Add(entity);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: Cant see your images. Also, you are calling translatorRepository.Add(language) operation. Does the repository have a Save() function too? The other problem I see is that in catch block you are simply returning blank view. If an error/exception occurs, your catch block is simply swallowing that problem, not making you aware of underlying issue. You need to move that return View(); statement outside catch block. change that catch to catch(Exception e){ Console.WriteLine(e.Message);} This will tell you what is failing. Note that this is not resolution, it simply tells you what the problem is.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your feedback.
I updated the repository it's actually doesn't contain the save action, but this error was occurred, and i tried every trick in the book with no result, please any idea??

Comment: Hi @LightoGamer, can you add try...catch... ,and we need check the detail about the exception.

Comment: Dear jason, i found the problem and i will add the answer below so other people can check it..

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the problem, I discovered that for some reason, when you create the relations between the project's tables and the AspNetUser table in a different Dbcontext than the ApplicationDbConrext, it creates a new table with the name ApplicatonUser separate from the original table.